# How to create Google Earth KML network link that does not allow folder to be expanded

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a network link that references another KML file with actual data to be loaded into Google Earth. My issue is that the number of points in the referenced KML file is so large that it crashes Google Earth if the KML file folder underneath the Places tab in Google Earth is set to "Allow this folder to be expanded" (right-click KML, properties). By default, this checkbox is checked. I want to make it so that for every network link I create the folder by default will not be expandable.

I have looked up checkHideChildren  in Google Earth KML tutorials, but that line provides no results, and I am not entirely sure where I am supposed to place the line in the Network Link KML.

Here is example code, if you could point me in the direction where to place this line of code, or an entirely different approach, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<NetworkLink>
<name>
CPU
</name>
<refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>
<Link id="GPS_Plotter Updater">
<href>CPU.kml</href>
<Style id="style1"><ListStyle>
<listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType> <-- this is the line that should be hiding the children points of the KML!
</ListStyle>
</Style>
<styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
<refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
<refreshInterval>1</refreshInterval>
<viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
<viewRefreshTime>1</viewRefreshTime>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Style element in the NetworkLink, not the Link element. Link doesn't take a style selector, but NetworkLink does. If that doesn't work, try a listItemType of radioFolder instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mano Marks' suggestions you also need to move the *styleUrl* element to the *NetworkLink* otherwise it won't apply. Note in your example you have *viewRefreshMode=onRegion* but don't have a region defined for it.

Here's the complete working example to suppress the NetworkLink contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <NetworkLink>
        <name>CPU</name>
        <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
        <Style id="style1">
                <ListStyle>
                    <listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType>
                </ListStyle>
        </Style>
        <Region>
                <!-- define region here -->
        </Region>
        <refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>        
        <Link id="GPS_Plotter_Updater">
            <href>CPU.kml</href>
            <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
            <refreshInterval>1</refreshInterval>
            <viewRefreshMode>onRegion</viewRefreshMode>
            <viewRefreshTime>1</viewRefreshTime>
        </Link> 
    </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

You can catch errors like this by validating your KML. Try using the Galdos [KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm).